# info: transport end (undefined)

Tags: node.js, socket.io, sails.js

In node application created using sails, while using console.log() method for showing the variables value in the terminal,

```
info: transport end (undefined)
```

is shown instead of the variable's value. What can be done to solve this ?

Comment: I have this feeling that will cause a silent error to be thrown which will cause socket.io to throw away that particular socket.

Comment: Try to get a minimal reproducible code here.

Comment: FYI, asked (with slightly more detail) and answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23485958/what-is-info-transport-end-undefined-in-sails-js).